# Array of ranges stores the same range. Why?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I have the following code in Word:

```
Function findRanges(keyword) As Variant()
    Dim foundRanges(), rngSearch As Range
    Dim i, foundCount As Integer

    i = 0
    foundCount = 0

    Set rngSearch = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rngSearch.Find
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=keyword, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
            foundCount = foundCount + 1
            rngSearch.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With

    ReDim foundRanges(0 To foundCount - 1)

    Set rngSearch = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rngSearch.Find
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=keyword, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
            Set foundRanges(i) = rngSearch
            MsgBox "rngSearch / " & rngSearch.End
            MsgBox "foundRanges / " & foundRanges(i).End
            i = i + 1
            rngSearch.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With

    For j = LBound(foundRanges) To UBound(foundRanges)
        MsgBox j & "foundRanges / " & foundRanges(j).End
    Next j

    findRanges = foundRanges
End Function
```

When I use this function, ranges stored in the array "foundRanges" are different (I check it by their End position). BUT as soon as my find loop ends, ranges become all the same (they have the same End position) and I can't get why.

What I want to do is to store locations of each found keyword in an array and change the keywords later to a user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [duplicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.duplicate) the range before storing it - otherwise you keep storing a reference to the same range, and this range keeps changing as you call `.Find()` repeatedly.

Something like this:

```
Function findRanges(keyword, Optional SearchIn As Range) As Variant()
    Dim foundRanges(), i As Integer

    If SearchIn Is Nothing Then Set SearchIn = ActiveDocument.Range

    Do While SearchIn.Find.Execute(FindText:=keyword, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True)
        ReDim Preserve foundRanges(i)
        Set foundRanges(i) = SearchIn.Duplicate
        SearchIn.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    findRanges = foundRanges
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! It works except "redim preserve" part as the array doesn't have dimesnsions at the first loop step. I solved it by adding "ReDim foundRanges(0)" before the find loop and "ReDim Preserve foundRanges(UBound(foundRanges) - 1)" after it. Is it ok or is there a better way?

Comment: This is exactly right, that was a bug in my code. Thanks! :)

Comment: You should  find that using a collection (or better a Scripting.Dictionary) is much simpler than using a variant array.

Comment: Collections are a bit easier to fill (call `.Add()` instead of calling `ReDim Preserve`), but arrays are a bit easier to iterate with a `For Each` loop. There is no need to re-write working code that uses arrays.